# Python: How to find missing number between 1 to 9?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I need to take in 3 different inputs to search against number 1 to 9.
If they don't exist between 1 to 9, I need to return the remaining value.

I have my code as below but it is not working.

```
def remaining_values(lst1, lst2, lst3):
legal_lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9] 
lst = lst1 + lst2 + lst3
return [x for x in range(lst[0], lst[-1]+1)  
                           if x not in lst]
```

It should pass this test:

```
def remaining_values():
    assert(legal_values([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]) == [4, 5, 6])
```

So if the list has 123 and 789, then it should return 456.

What do I need to change on my code to achieve that?

Comment: Is `legal_values()` and `remaining_values()` supposed to be the same function?

Comment: And 8 is not in legal_lst.

Answer (score 2):

You can use sets to find missing numbers in a range:

```
legal_lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]
print(set(range(1,10)) - set(legal_lst))
```

Output

```
{8}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is wrong, I suppose that's formatting issue, try

```
def remaining_values(lst1, lst2, lst3):
    legal_lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9] 
    lst = lst1 + lst2 + lst3
    return [x for x in lst if x not in legal_lst]
```

More on list comprehension [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a sets:

```
def test_sudoku(lst1,lst2,lst3):
  legal_lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]
  return list(set(lst1+lst2+lst3) - set(legal_lst))
```